# How do i add event for delete catagory, with same method which i used in add event?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category, event-observer

```
<config>
   <modules>
        <Ab_CategoryObserver>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Ab_CategoryObserver>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ab_categoryobserver>
                <class>Ab_CategoryObserver_Model</class>
            </ab_categoryobserver>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_category_save_commit_after><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <ab_categoryobserver>
                        <class>ab_categoryobserver/observer</class>
                        <method>updateTopMenuJson</method>
                    </ab_categoryobserver>
                </observers>
            </catalog_category_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the tag `events` add this:

```
        <catalog_category_delete_after><!-- observe the event -->
            <observers>
                <ab_categoryobserver>
                    <class>ab_categoryobserver/observer</class>
                    <method>updateTopMenuJson</method>
                </ab_categoryobserver>
            </observers>
        </catalog_category_delete_after>
```